# how to make a delay to wait for the map to load

Tags: openlayers-2, ext-js

What code could I use to make it wait for the program to load the map first after the zoomIn command?

Here's a part of my code.

```js
for (var z = zoomfrom; z <= zoomto; z++) { 
    var scale = MapPanel.map.getScale();
    var zoomlevel = MapPanel.map.getZoom();
    NewZoomLevel = getzoomlevel(scale); 
    lat1 = lat2tile(coords.top, NewZoomLevel);
    lat2 = lat2tile(coords.bottom, NewZoomLevel);

    long1 = long2tile(coords.left, NewZoomLevel);
    long2 = long2tile(coords.right, NewZoomLevel);

    for (var x= lat1; x<=lat2; x++) {
         for (var y= long1; y<=long2; y++) {
              list = list + startlink + zoomlevel + '/' + x + '/' + y + '<br>';
        } //y for
    } //x for
    MapPanel.map.zoomIn();

    // this part im hoping to put a code to wait for map to load after zoomIn                                                                                               
}; // z for
```

I tried using delayed function of extjs but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript you can't "delay" code execution to wait for a certain event to happen, you need to use completion callbacks. `OpenLayers.Map` has a [range of events you can listen to](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.events), the one you need is `zoomend`:

> **zoomend**    triggered after a zoom completes

Here's a simple example based on your code:

```
var map = MapPanel.map;
map.events.register('zoomend', map, function() {
  console.log('Zoom completed!');
});

console.log('About to zoom in');
map.zoomIn();
console.log('Zoom in started');
```

You can test it directly in your browser by pasting the code above (without the first line) into the JavaScript console on http://openlayers.org/. The output confirms that the execution order is what you'd expect:

> About to zoom in
>
> Zoom in started
>
> Zoom completed!

---

However, it's not clear what you need the `list` variable for - depending on whether you'd like to use it *before* or *after* the zoom event you may need to rejiggle your code a bit.

Comment: i'm actually gonna use the list. it's supposed to be a container for links and it will show it after all the Z loop finishes. erm.. what's a completion callback? i never heard it.

Comment: There are loads of articles explaining that, google for "JavaScript callback" (SO for example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3523628/1240557). Did you *try* using the `zoomend` event as described above? Are you still having problems?

Comment: yup. i checked it out. didn't work out. tried using loadend event at the moment. it might work seeing the loadend example on Openlayers.

Comment: maybe i should change my question. what I wanted is to "wait" for all the tiles of the baselayer to be loaded after zoomIn was fired and the for loop to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

In Openlayers there is **loadend** event to listen to layer(s) and not map when it is loaded, check below code & link:

```
var mylayer = ''//Openlayers layer object
mylayer.events.register("loadend", mylayer, function() { 
   console.log('layer loaded');
});
```

**link:** http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/layerLoadMonitoring.html